# Is a dual of continuous functions with values in a Banach a distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Take $X:=C([0,T];L^1(\Omega))$ with $\Omega$ an open bounded regular domain. I'd like to show to which space of distributions $X'$ belongs.

If for instance we do not have vector valued continuous functions (for instance if $X:=C([0,T])$) then the answer is standard and it is possible to 
prove that $X'$ is actually the subset of ${\cal D}'((-1,T+1))$ for instance s.t. the support is  $\subseteq [0,T]$) and a possible arguments are presented partly [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1120177/pre-dual-of-distributions-with-support-in-a-closed-subset/1121947#1121947).

In the more general case if $X:=([0,T]\times{\mathbb R}_+;L^1(\Omega))$, the same question holds and should be a little more involved since 
the "time" domain is only locally compact.

Is there a reference where such questions are solved in a standard way ?

Thanks for suggestions and comments